# Does "Consolidated Financial Data" and "Form 8-K" and similar legal terms count as named entities (for Named Entity Recognition)?

Tags: named-entity-recognition, edgar

Thanks for helping. I am doing some named entity tagging and came across a few ambiguous terms.
I follow mostly the CoNLL2003 annotation guidelines and MUC-7 named entity definition (other annotation guidelines mostly share the same idea with these guidelines)

https://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/conll2003/ner/

https://www-nlpir.nist.gov/related_projects/muc/proceedings/ne_task.html

For the example sentence "I do business in North and South America", how should I tag "North and South America"? The whole phrase as one "Location" entity, or "North" and "South America" as two "Location" entities?

I am tagging some legal reports (EDGAR dataset from US Securities and Exchange Commission), so I encounter phrases like "Form 10", "Form 8-K", which are types of legal forms for US companies. Should these be treated as "Miscellaneous" named entities?

In these forms there are chapter names such as "Consolidated Financial Statements", "Management's Discussion and Analysis", should these be tagged as "Miscellaneous"?

If yes then phrases like "Annual Report", "Annual Meeting for Shareholders", "Common Stock", "Restricted Stock Unit" becomes quite ambiguous. It can be argued that they are the name of a type of "legal documents", or the name of type of "Financial Instruments". But these phrases are generic somehow and do not pinpoint one specific entity. Should they be "Miscellaneous" or "Outside of a named entity" (Not a Named entity)?